# Linking Boost Thread: No rule to make target ".../libpthread.so"

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-thread

I am trying to cross-compile a project on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 WSL for the Raspberry Pi. I have installed the toolchain via `sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`, so it's located unter `/usr/bin/`.

Now in my CMake File I've set the following:

```
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
    set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

    set(SYSROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../raspi_root")
    
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++")
    
    set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${SYSROOT})
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${SYSROOT})
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

`raspi_root` is the location of my RaspberryPi root file system that I copied from the pi to my WSL.

The CMakeLists.txt then continues in this manner:

```
set(project_target Project)
project(${project_target})

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    <All my other sources>
    )

add_executable(${project_target} ${SOURCES})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS atomic thread system chrono REQUIRED)
find_library(ALLOTHERLIBS otherlibs REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${project_target} PUBLIC 
    ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${SYSROOT}/usr/include
    ${SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
    )

target_link_libraries(${project_target} PUBLIC
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${ALLOTHERLIBS}
    )
```

Now wenn I do `cmake` the MakeFile is generated and (almost)* everything succeeds. However, when doing `make`, I get the following error message:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../raspi_root/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so', needed by 'Project'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To me, still learning CMake and Make, this looks like it's trying to compile the already compiled library `libpthread.so`. This error disappears when I remove thread from the required boost components. However, then of course the program won't compile because I do use the boost::thread library.

What could be the issue? Why is cmake trying to "make" libpthread.so? Wouldn't any errors concerning the shared library usually appear while linking?

I'm lost for a few days already. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards
Felix

*I say almost because find_package(boost) gives the following warning:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1558 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)
```

However, my not too thorough Google search told me that this is due to some version difference between CMake and Boost and can be ignored.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like Boost::thread uses pthread, and `make` is looking for a `arm-linux-gnueabihf` version of the pthread library. Do you have one installed? If so, `make` cannot find it, so you may have to point CMake to where it exists...

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I haven't looked into this earlier. The library is installed and make finds the link to the library but that link was broken by rsyncing the root file system. So
`libpthread.so -> "Raspberrys absolute Path"/libpthread.so"
I will have to repair those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found my mistake, thanks to @squareskittles.
When I used rsync to copy the root file system of my Raspberry Pi to my WSL, it "broke" all the links. So in this case `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so` pointed to the absolute path of the library, namely `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0`.
However on my machine this path was different, since it was located in my raspi_root folder.

I repaired the link with a variant of this handy command (Credits to [Mark Wagner](https://serverfault.com/a/352031))

```
find ../raspi_root -type l -ls |
awk '$13 ~ /^\// { sub("/","/<MYPATH-TO-RASPI_ROOT/", $13); print $11, $13 }' |
while read A B; do rm $A; ln -s $B $A; done
```

If I understand correctly this retrieves all links and checks if the destination (argument $13 of find result) starts with '/' meaning the link refers to an absolute path. Then, it replaces the first occurence of '/' with my new path to the root file system.

I think this implies that I must not move or rename the root folder or my links will be broken again.